# jQuery Form plugin - how to prevent double submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

There are several threads on this here at SO but I didn't find one that deals specifically with the awesome [jQuery Form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) which I use extensively in my app.

I want the user to be able to click 'submit' only once -- and disable the 'submit' button until Ajax has returned a JSON string on success.

My trial code goes something like this

```
$('#submit_button').live('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var options = {
    type:           'post',
    dataType:       'json',
    beforeSubmit:   function(){
                        $('#loading').show().fadeIn();
                        $('#submit_button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    },
    success:        function(data) {
                            if (data.success === 3) {
                                $('#submit_button').hide();
                                $('#loading').hide();
                                $('#validation_message').html(data.message).fadeIn();
                                $('#submit_button').attr('enabled', 'enabled');
                            }
                    }
            }

$(this).closest('form').ajaxSubmit(options);
});
```

But this piles up "enabled" and "disabled" attributes in the `<button>`.

```
<button class="button" id="submit_button" disabled="disabled" enabled="enabled"> Post </button>
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting attribute "enabled" to "enabled", you will want to unset the "disabled" attribute: `$('#submit_button').attr('disabled', '');`

HTML does not have an "enabled" attribute for buttons, so the browser isn't going to do anything with it - it considers it just a "junk" attribute. Setting and unsetting the "disabled" attribute is what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

try:

in success handler add this line..

```
 $('#submit_button').removeAttr('disabled');
```

delete this line in the success handler:

```
$('#submit_button').attr('enabled', 'enabled');
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't test it right now, but using [removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) should help (Remove enabled in the beforeSubmit part and counterwise in the success).